# How can I reset the filters of react-admin list

Tags: react-admin

In a page I have a button to another list showing the filtered results:

```
 <Button
        color="primary"
        component={Link}
        to={{
            pathname: '/jobseekers',
            search: `filter=${JSON.stringify({ skills: record.id })}`,
        }}
    >
        Job Seekers
   </Button>
```

However, when I click on the menu for `jobseekers` resource, I get the filtered results. It passes filtering options in the url to the backend, I don't know how to reset them when the `jobseeks` on the menu was clicked.

I tried these on my list but they have no effect, it says `setFilters` isn't a function, also console shows that the `listContext` has null values for filters

```
import { useListContext } from 'react-admin';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const MemberList = ({ permissions, hasDelete, hasEdit, hasShow, resource, ...props }) => {
    const listContext = useListContext();
    listContext.setFilters({}, []);
    useEffect(() => {
       listContext.filterValues = null
       listContex.tsetFilters({}, []);
         console.log("mem list context:",listContext)
    }, [listContext, props]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official documentation [Resetting Filters On Menu Click](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Menu.html#resetting-filters-on-menu-click):

By default, a click on `<Menu.Item >` for a list page opens the list with the same filters as they were applied the last time the user saw them. This is usually the expected behavior, but your users may prefer that clicking on a menu item resets the list filters.

Just use an empty `filter` query parameter to force empty filters:

```
<Menu.Item
    to="/posts?filter=%7B%7D" // %7B%7D is JSON.stringify({})
    primaryText="Posts"
    leftIcon={<BookIcon />}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I use `Filter` in my list page, then after loading the page, it automatically selects those filters and the user will know that the filters are active and can remove them:

```
const JobSeekerFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
      <SearchInput source="q" alwaysOn />
      <ReferenceInput label="Skills" source="skills" reference="skills">
        <SelectInput label="Skills" optionText="name" />
      </ReferenceInput>
    </Filter>
  )
```

and

```
  <List {...props} filters={<JobSeekerFilter />}>
```